# Select DATEADD minutes with query SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

```
SELECT
   [NAMENO],
   [FIRSTNAME],
   [MIDNAME],
   [LASTNAME],
   [SEX],
   [STATUSOF],
   [RELEASEDT],
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DOBDT, 101) AS DOBDT 
FROM
   database
WHERE 
   ReleaseDT >= dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,60,GETDATE()),0)
   AND ReleaseDT < dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

I am wanting to get anyone that has a "releasedt" in the past 60 mins if that makes of sense? right now its pull the last 60 days..

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just:

```
where ReleaseDT >= dateadd(minute, -60, getdate())
and ReleaseDT <= getdate()
```

Nesting `dateadd` and `datediff` (like you did in your code in the question) is not necessary.
In fact, `datediff` calculates the difference (in hours, minutes...whatever) between two datetime values, so you don't need it at all when you just want to get "now minus 60 minutes".